# Android NDK Include Path In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have an Android NDK project that builds fine in cygwin using ndk-build.

However, I wanted to have it build in eclipse, so I installed C/C++ Development tools into my ADT version of eclipse and added native support to the project in eclipse.  However, after building, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: timer.h: No such file or directory
```

In my original Android.mk file, I have the following include that lets it work in cygwin:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /cygdrive/c/ADT/includes/
```

I tried adding a similar include path (C:\ADT\includes) to Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols, but still no luck.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to use windows paths 
    `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := C:/ADT/includes/`

Note that using the following works as well (per cpu2's answer)

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -IC:/ADT/includes/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `-I/path/to/includes` to your cflags.